# Default value when calling a function in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, default, random-forest

Suppose I want to iterate over different values with a for loop in a function (e.g. randomForest)

```
for (i in c(100, 200, 500)){
randomForest(Predictor ~., data = train, ntree = i)}
```

One of the values, passed to randomForest function that I want to evaluate is the **default value** (suppose that I don't know that the default value of ntree in randomForest is 500)

How can I specify that in the for loop?

```
for (i in c(100,200, default)){
randomForest(Predictor ~., data = train, ntree = i)}
```

Comment: what's wrong with passing 500 directly like you did in the first loop ?

Comment: I can think of several really complicated ways to do this, but probably I'd just designate some "unusual" value like -1 or NA as the "default" and put an `if ... else` in your for loop and modify the `randomForest` call appropriately.

Comment: @YOLO Some 'default values' may depend on the given dataset (number of variables, predictors, and so on), therefore, I wanted to know an appropriate method which can be useful in that situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look up the value with `formals`, which gives you a list which includes all the default values. But it comes with its own set of problems, as not all functions handle things the exact same way.

The first problem becomes clear in your example: `formals(randomForest)` only gives you `x` and `...`, both without defaults. That is because randomForest is a generic method, which accepts different arguments based on the class of the first one. To get the default for `ntree`, you need

```
formals(randomForest:::randomForest.default)$ntree
```

Some more problems I can think of:

- It may not be even clear what a missing or default value is. Ever seen the difference between `somedataframe[1]` and `somedataframe[1,]` or `somedataframe[,1]`? What is the default?
- What about optional arguments that are given another value inside a function? Take for example a plot: if you don't specify anything, it generates its own title. But what is the "default" title?
- For some functions, there is a difference as to *where* an argument comes from, where it is evaluated. This matters particularly when dealing with environments, so that `match.call()` and `match.call` with all arguments filled in as specified by the defaults, will give different results.

So put all together, I think you're better off just placing a call outside the loop, or calling with an `if ... else`

Answer (score 2):

You can't really pass in "missing" argument values in R. If you want to make sure the default value is included in the list of things you are iterating over, i'd recommend

```
values <- unique(c(100, 200, formals(randomForest:::randomForest.default)$ntree))
for (i in valies){
  randomForest(Predictor ~., data = train, ntree = i)}
```

Here we just use `formals()` on the function to get the default value and I used `unique()` to make sure that value wasn't already included.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding this to the mix, because I kind of like that it is simple and readable, just as an option:

```
for (i in c(100,200,NA)){
  if (is.na(i)){ 
    randomForest(Predictor ~., data = train)
  } else{
    randomForest(Predictor ~., data = train,ntree = i)
  }
}
```